# nom galio-framework missing ./fonts/galio.ttf

Tags: react-native

I'm using galio-framework in my react native project. I installed galio-framewor using `npm i galio-framework` https://www.npmjs.com/package/galio-framework.

However, when I run my expo project, it returns the warning:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Could not download from './fonts/galio.ttf']
```

The icon/fonts are not being loaded in my project. How can I install galio.ttf?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution for this? I'm running into the same issue